# Can a Toolstrip and Toolstrip Textbox have the same color?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, toolstrip

I am using a `Toolstrip` on a Windows Form. On this `Toolstrip` I placed a `Textbox`. I am not able to give the `Textbox` the same color as the Toolstrip and `BackColor` transparent is not possible.

Toolstrip `BackColor` = Control and Textbox `BackColor` = ControlLightLight.

Comment: Picture might help here.  You can try `toolStripTextBox1.BackColor = toolStrip1.BackColor;` or `toolStripTextBox1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from Textbox to Label. Since I am just trying to display some text the label works fine and the BackColor can be set to Transparent.